# Can I beat the "Beachhead" quests without doing anything?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have done a number of the "Beachhead" quests now for Nola, and it feels like there aren't enough birds and crabs to prevent all the juvenile turtles from making it to the water.

So, that got me wondering - with sufficient time on my hands, could I theoretically sit there and do nothing and still have enough turtles get to the water to complete the quest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, that won't work.

The birds aren't the problem, but the crabs keep coming. The crabs walk to one of the spots where the turtles cross their path and stay there. After a few minutes those spots are all covered and nothing goes through anymore.

[image]